# How to detect xpath of 3 separate dropdowns with similar id, names, index postion?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

If 3 of the dropdowns like in the screenshots got similar id names and all. How to locate them then? 3 of them have got similar xpaths. How to detect them?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS4fx.png)

Comment: You can detect all the dropdowns uniquely using different [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and HTML as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use findElements to identify all of them and use index to identify them.

   ```
   List<WebElement> elementName = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='formrow-inputSector']"));
   ```
2. You can use relative location strategy like parent, ancestor or child
   Assuming there is a div containing 'Choose Organization' and choose product inside the select. ( or if select itself contains the text - use `text() = 'Choose Organization'` - this won't work if there is some other value selected previously)

   ```
   WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[child::*//*[text()='Choose Organization']]"))
   ```

or use siblings, ancestors or parent

(https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html - For Reference )